# multidex - NoClassDefFoundError with multidex enabled

Tags: android, kotlin, android-multidex

My app is crashing on pre-21 with `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError app.module.SomeClass` error.

I already have Multidex enabled:

build.gradle:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
}

dependencies {
   ...
   implementation "androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1"
}
```

My Application class:

```
class App : DaggerApplication() {
    ...
    override fun attachBaseContext(base: Context) {
        super.attachBaseContext(base)
        MultiDex.install(this)
    }
```

After reading about [Declaring classes required in the primary DEX file](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html#keep) I created `multidex-config.pro` file to include `app.module.**` in primary DEX file:

```
-keep class app.module.** { *; }
```

And registered it in build.gradle:

```
android {
  buildTypes {
    debug {
      ...
      multiDexKeepProguard file('multidex-config.pro')
    }
}
```

I confirmed it by checking `build/intermediates/legacy_multidex_main_dex_list/debug/mainDexList.txt` and analyzing the debug apk (checking whether `classes.dex` includes `app.module.SomeClass`).

But I'm still getting `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError app.module.SomeClass` error.

I also tried cleaning caches, running on different machines (cli build only without Android Studio), disabling instant run, specifying `javaMaxHeapSize`, just extending `MultiDexApplication` and etc.

What can I try next?

Comment: Use this -keep public class app.module.** { *; }

Comment: @MahabubKarim I tried, no effect.

Comment: why is `multiDexKeepProguard file('multidex-config.pro')` in the debug config?

Comment: @ArchieG.Quiñones because the app is crashing in both debug & release builds.

Comment: correct me if I'm wrong but you check if `app.module.SomeClass` is present after multidex and it is there? that doesn't sound like a produard issue. Have you tried removing proguard optimization?

Comment: @ArchieG.Quiñones Yes, I tried removing proguard (and proguard is disabled for debug builds).

Comment: is instant run disabled ?

Comment: Hey @alashow what gradle version are you using ?

Comment: @LevonPetrosyan I'm using gradle's v5.4

Comment: I am not sure about `multiDexKeepProguard`, but try  this `proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile( 'proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'yourProguardRuleFile' `

Comment: @LevonPetrosyan I tried disabling proguard itself for Release builds. Regardless, the crash is present in Debug builds too.

Answer (score 8):

We had a deeper look at this here:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/131100011

There is an unfortunate bug in some Dalvik VMs on pre-21 devices where package private methods were sometimes incorrectly overriden by public methods in another package. If the package private method is final, that will then lead to errors of the form:

`E/dalvikvm: Method Lcom/mycompany/MyViewModel;.clear overrides final Landroidx/lifecycle/ViewModel;.clear`

It looks like that could be what is hitting you here. Unfortunately, the only workaround for that particular issue is to rename your "clear" method to something else so that you do not hit this unfortunate VM bug.

Comment: Thanks for this, this really help.

Answer (score 4):

### Try below steps hope it will help you

```
dependencies { 
 compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1' 
}
```

Config your source
Declare MultiDexApplication class in AndroidManifest.xml file

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication">
</application>
```

If we can’t extend MultiDexApplication we can install multiple dex files manually by overriding attachBaseContext(Context base) method in our Application class

```
public class HelloMultiDexApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }
@Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
        super.attachBaseContext(base);
        MultiDex.install(this);
    }
}
```

Config dexOptions in app/build.gradle

```
android {
    dexOptions {
        incremental true         
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
}
```

Enable multidex in app/build.gradle

```
android {
 defaultConfig { 
  multiDexEnabled true 
 }
}
afterEvaluate {
    tasks.matching {
        it.name.startsWith('dex')
    }.each { dx ->
        if (dx.additionalParameters == null) {
            dx.additionalParameters = ['--multi-dex']
        } else {
            dx.additionalParameters += '--multi-dex'
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
 compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1' 
}
```

Disabled pre-dexing each module at the end of root build.gradle

```
subprojects {
    project.plugins.whenPluginAdded { plugin ->
        if ("com.android.build.gradle.AppPlugin".equals(plugin.class.name)) {
            project.android.dexOptions.preDexLibraries = false
        } else if ("com.android.build.gradle.LibraryPlugin".equals(plugin.class.name)) {
            project.android.dexOptions.preDexLibraries = false
        }
    }
}
```

Increase gradle jvm build in gradle.properties

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4608M
```

Answer (score 1):

In your app gradle file add this

```
android {
    ...
    dexOptions {
        jumboMode = true
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
     }
     defaultConfig {
         ...
```

**javaMaxHeapSize**

Specify the maximum size, in bytes, of the memory allocation pool. This value must a multiple of 1024 greater than 2MB. Append the letter k or K to indicate kilobytes, or m or M to indicate megabytes. The default value is chosen at runtime based on system configuration.

Answer (score 1):

try changing the order of instructions for `DaggerApplication`:

```
override fun onCreate() {
    MultiDex.install(this)
    super.onCreate()
}
```

because the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex) reads:

> **Caution**: Do not execute `MultiDex.install()` or any other code through reflection or JNI before `MultiDex.install()` is complete. Multidex tracing will not follow those calls, causing `ClassNotFoundException` or verify errors due to a bad class partition between DEX files.

Comment: Moving `Multidex.install()` there cause actual multidex issues with other classes. I tried removing everything from my app class and just extending from `MultiDexApplication`

Comment: @alashow when it only crashes < API 21, this hints for the library not properly installed... because later the library is not required anymore. `DaggerApplication` might behave differently than `Application`. `<application android:name` in the `Manifest.xml` might be missing; this ordinary defines the `Application` entry point.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
dexOptions {
            preDexLibraries = false
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I use to have this issue when making ADB builds for ice cream sandwich (API 14) devices.

What worked for me was [disabling Android Studio's instant run](https://github.com/ftctechnh/ftc_app/wiki/Disabling-Android-Studio-Instant-Run).