# ViewModelProviders not finding my ViewModel class on API 19

Tags: android, androidx

I'm trying to create my ViewModel class in Android 4.4 (API 19) but an error is thrown.
I've tried to execute on Android 5.1 and works fine.

Import:

```
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProviders
```

Code:

```
mViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this)[SplashScreenViewModel::class.java]
```

Error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.nddprint.nddprinthplink.viewmodel.SplashScreenViewModel
    at com.nddprint.nddprinthplink.view.splash.SplashScreenFragment.onCreate(SplashScreenFragment.kt:36)
    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:2586)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:838)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addAddedFragments(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2100)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1874)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1830)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1727)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2663)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2613)
    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performActivityCreated(Fragment.java:2624)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:904)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1238)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1303)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2659)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2613)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:246)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:542)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:201)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1171)
    at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5241)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2168)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49038667/runtimeexceptionclassnotfoundexception-android-arch-lifecycle-processlifecycleo

Comment: thanks for trying to help, but didn't work.

Answer (score 6):

Maybe this could help you.

[multidex - NoClassDefFoundError with multidex enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55803196/multidex-noclassdeffounderror-with-multidex-enabled)

There is an issue that you can not have a method in your ViewModel (in your case SplashScreenViewModel) with the name of clear().

If this is your problem, rename that method. I hope this could help you.